# Update attribute on table based on lowest ranking attribute from other table mySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using MySQL for the following: I have 2 tables, `sw_products` and `sw_components`. Each `sw_product` can be made up of multiple `sw_components`. And there is another relation table where each row specifies the product and a component it is uses.

Each `sw_component` has a status: 'ready', 'not-ready', and 'unusable'. And each `sw_product` also has a status which corresponds to the lowest status of all of its components.

What I was doing was trying was to create a TRIGGER UPDATE when `sw_components` updates, but then I'd need to cycle through all the `sw_products` that use that `sw_component` and change their status if the new status is higher. How can I do this inside a trigger? (assign a variable to a select statement, and cycle through each row, maybe?)

[image: Here are the tables I've created]

Thanks!

Comment: you can use a cursor inside the trigger and get the job done!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m the OP. I was able to solve the problem after some thinking. As Ultimater said, you can use cursors, but they´re read only, so you can go into some trouble, and I thought they were over-complicated (but still, thanks!).

What I did was changed the status from VARCHARS to INTEGERS, then I created a View of each product alongside their lowest status (using a MIN(status):

```
CREATE VIEW product_status_by_component AS
SELECT s_name, s_version, min(status) AS min
FROM sw_components
JOIN sw_build
ON sw_components.name = c_name AND sw_components.version = c_version
GROUP BY s_name, s_version;
```

Then I used a trigger each time a components status got updated. I found out you Update unrelated tables even if the trigger does not belong to them, and that you could join tables inside an update:

```
UPDATE sw_products a 
    LEFT JOIN product_status_by_component b ON
        a.name = b.s_name AND a.version = b.s_version
    SET 
        a.status = b.min;
```